# How do you set up opera driver or any other driver in ubuntu after downloading the zip file?

Tags: linux, selenium, robotframework, operadriver

I am new to automation, I am working on ubuntu OS, right now I have a couple of test cases in robot framework, I am trying to run them using opera browser, but I do not know how to install the driver after I downloaded the zip from here:

https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

What are the steps to set this up?

Comment: you don't install the driver.  just copy it to somewhere on your system PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Well in case somebody needs it i solved it, these are the steps:

```
1. Go to https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases
2. Right click on  operadriver_linux64.zip 
3. Copy link address 
4. Open Terminal 
5. type wget https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases/download/v.78.0.3904.87/operadriver_linux64.zip (this is the address you copied before)
6. unzip operadriver_linux64.zip
7. sudo mv operadriver /usr/bin/operadriver
8. sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/operadriver
9. sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/operadriver
10. Verify it is correct installation by typing... which operadriver (you should get the path like usr/bin/operadriver.
```

Comment: operadriver doesn't have to go in /usr/bin. It can be in any folder that is in your PATH.